# Calling a method from one class inside another method from another class

Tags: java, class, constructor

I am working on creating a basic library system in Java, as this is my final assignment for my school year. At the moment, I am having some trouble with certain functions, as the program uses multiple classes and methods to perform tasks.

The main issue I am having is with the Calendar class interacting with the book class for creating a due date when a book is checked out.

This is what I would like to be able to do:

```
public class Calendar{
    private  int currentDate;

    public Calendar(int currentDate){
      Calendar calendar = new Calendar(0);
    }  
    public int getCurrentDate() {
      return currentDate;
    }
} 
public class Book{
  private int dueDate;

  public void checkOut(int dueDate){
    dueDate = (calendar.getCurrentDate()) + 7;
  }
```

All I really need to know is if this or something similar is possible.

Some parts of the code are omitted because I didn't think they would be necessary to see, but a link to the full program is right here if it helps: https://repl.it/@BryceBrown1/Library-System

Comment: Either you create an instance of `Calendar` inside `Book` class, or you make the method `getCurrentDate()` static to have it accessible without an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending in a `dueDate` to the `checkOut` method, send in a `calendar` instance.

Also, don't try to create a `Calendar` in the `Calendar` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewriting the wheel why not using `java.time.LocalDate` type from jdk?

```java
public class Book{
  private LocalDate dueDate;

  public void checkOut(){
    dueDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(7);
  }
```